# Tailwind not automatically updating styles without npm run build-css

Tags: tailwind-css

This is my first time using Tailwind and I'm stuck just setting it up.
I'm following a course on Udemy and I've gone over every step twice but mine just isn't working like it is in the video.

Styles applied with Tailwind are working but every time I add something new in, I have to use `npm run build-css` to see any of the changes.

When watching the video, he'll put in a new style class and just save it then refresh the browser and the changes are there.

Is there something I'm missing here?
I've been hunting around for an answer for a while and can't find any help.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "package.json",
  "main": "tailwind.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build -i style.css -o css/style.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

style.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Try to change `build-css` script into `tailwindcss -i style.css -o css/style.css --watch`

Comment: Good! I would suggest keep both scripts for compiling and watch modes. List of all possible options for build script you may find [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/cli.js#L194)

Answer (score 2):

Using the build command will only update the output file on that instance. You should be using the watch command so the output file is constantly being updated. Here are the scripts I'm using to develop with Tailwind.

/ package.json /

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build-css": "tailwindcss build -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css",
  "watch-css": "tailwindcss build -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css --watch",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run watch-css\" \"npm start\""
},
```

Run "npm run watch-css" instead of "npm run build-css" [Replace the file location with your own files. After -i is the location of your input css file, after -o is the location of your output css file].

If you're trying to use React, you can install [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run scripts simultaneously. In this case I'm starting my local ReactJS project and I'm watching the Tailwind output file. Or you could just open two terminals and run both scripts.

There's good information in the [TailwindCSS Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something missed on html file to link up CSS. I just copy your code and added this html.

Check the screenshot the same structure you have.
https://prnt.sc/knox4-8NCK2e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tailwind CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-red-300 h-40">
        <h1 class="text-2xl">Tailwind CSS works</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now Run Command :

1. npm install
2. npm run build-css

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have the css file linked in index.html. The styles do work but the issue is that I have to do npm run build-css every time I change anything in order to see those changes

Comment: to avoid every-time build, you have to run npm dev server, that will work like charm without build everytime. You do code and it will change automatically in browser.

I would to like to request  you this boilerplate : https://github.com/hasinhayder/tailwind-boilerplate

just clone it and follow the instruction on readme file. if its not helpful, feel free to comment again. I will help you in other way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I run watch instead of build, and it solved my problem.

```
npm run watch
```

this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ( the -i and the -w )  this to ur package.json file   that's valide for me
`"scripts": { "build-css": "tailwindcss build -i src/styles.css -o public/styles.css -w" },`